# How to merge reposA's subdirectory to reposB's root directory?

Tags: git

I have two repositories - reposA and reposB, the struct as below.

```
reposA\  
       sub_dict\  
                A1.txt   
                A2.txt    

reposB\         
       READ.ME
```

I want to merge files from A to B, then the struct looks like that

```
reposB\
       READ.ME  
       A1.txt   
       A2.txt
```

I add reposA as my remote upstream and use git read-tree to merge, and I did it.

Here are my commands:

```
$ git remote add -f reposA git://git.git  
$ git merge -s ours --no-commit reposA/master  
$ git read-tree --prefix=/ -u reposA/master:sub_dict  
$ git commit -m "commits"
```

At the Step.4, reposB's root directory has already had the same files with reposA's sub_dict.

But, **when the reposA add a new file A3.txt. I don't know how to pull the A3.txt to reposB.**

The error message is:

> error: Entry 'XXX' overlaps with 'XXX'. Cannot bind.

Comment: Format your code as code example, please.

Comment: You can't do like that. You need to (re-)construct your reposB each time reposA has been updated.

Comment: If you can use symlinks , add repo `A` as submodule of repo `B` , create your link into B linking to file of repo A